# What is the native header attribute?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
namespace UnityEngine
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Base class for everything attached to GameObjects.
    [NativeClassAttribute("Unity::Component")]
    [NativeHeaderAttribute("Runtime/Export/Scripting/Component.bindings.h")]
    [RequiredByNativeCodeAttribute]
    public class Component : Object
    {
        .
        .
```

As I was deep-diving into the code I came across these attributes, what are these attributes ?

Comment: Probably an internal header in the Unity codebase which links the Managed C# side of the code with the Native C++ side, to be picked up by internal tooling. Not something you as a user are expected to use.